# What is "Subject patients to radiation"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage, word-meaning

**[SOURCE](https://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes292033.htm)** (Job description)

> Prepare, administer, and measure radioactive isotopes in therapeutic, diagnostic, and tracer studies using a variety of radioisotope equipment. Prepare stock solutions of radioactive materials and calculate doses to be administered by radiologists. **Subject patients to radiation.** Execute blood volume, red cell survival, and fat absorption studies following standard laboratory techniques.

What is "Subject patients to radiation" here?

Can you provide the definition of subject from a reputable source to address my problem?

I think in this situation it can be either the patient is affected by the radiation or the technologist is affected by the radiation. Also, isn't that "Subject" can mean deal with something?

Answer (score 1):

This is using the last definition of "subject" [listed by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subject):

> : to cause or force to undergo or endure (something unpleasant, inconvenient, or trying)

In this case the statement is saying that part of the nuclear medicine technologist's job is to cause patients to undergo radiation.

Answer (score 0):

*Subject* here is a verb.  (Bee misreads it as an adjective.)  The sentence means “cause patients to be exposed to radiation”.

Answer (score -1):

The phase "Subject to" is a pretty common idiom which has two meanings:

- Likely to experience
- One thing needs to happen before another. ("This is subject to that", implies *that* can't happen before *this*)

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subject-to-something)

In your case, it just means that the patience will experience radiation.